# Execute Data Flow Task based on condition in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am very new to SSIS and I am building a package which will import files. I have a Execute SQL Task which will execute a SQL statement which will return files that needs to be imported, but the files will need to go into different tables depending on which file is being imported.

I have 2 Data Flow Tasks in my foreach container but now based on the file type it needs to execute 1 of them

How can I achieve this?

[image]

**EDIT**

This is the query that will be executed:

```
SELECT ReconMedicalAidFile.fReconMedicalAidFileID,   ReconMedicalAidFile.fReconMedicalAidID, 
ReconMedicalAids.fMedicalAidID, ReconMedicalAidFile.fFileName, 
ReconMedicalAidFile.fFileLocation, ReconMedicalAidFile.fFileImportedDate, ReconMedicalAidFile.fNumberRecords, ReconMedicalAidFile.fUser, 
ReconMedicalAidFile.fIsImported
FROM ReconMedicalAidFile INNER JOIN
ReconMedicalAids ON ReconMedicalAidFile.fReconMedicalAidID = ReconMedicalAids.fReconMedicalAidID
WHERE (fIsImported = 0) AND (fNumberRecords = 0)
```

So the condition is based on *fMedicalAidID*

Comment: I assume you have multiple files, hence the `ForEach` loop. How are the file types recognized? By the extension?

Comment: I have a flag column in my table which will indicate which file is which

Comment: Please post sample data from your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dummy script approach:
[image: DummyScript]

In the expressions for the two precedence constraints you evaluate a variable that is set either by the first SQL task or the script task.
[image]

Now, the data will flow down one of the two data flow paths based on the value of the variable.
The script task can be empty, or it can perform the logic needed to set the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to do what you want in SSIS with the way your current package is designed.

An alternate approach:

1. Add a `Conditional Split` task after the first `Execute SQL` task
2. Split based on file type
3. Create a separate `ForEach Loop` and `Execute SQL` task for each file type

Comment: Unable to add Conditional Split in the Control Flow, it can only be added in the Data Flow.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to set a variable in the foreach that gets passed to the Data Flow and from there to do the split?

Comment: What are you doing with the result set from the first `Execute SQL` task?

Comment: I set it to a object type variable and that is where it should iterate through the results

Comment: You can use a dummy script task in place of a conditional split.  Just use two outputs with expressions in the constraints.